# Clean $Recycle Bin Folders For Redirected Folders

Tags: windows-sbs-2011, folder-redirection

We have redirected folders for users desktops / my documents etc.

Using Treesize I can see that these folders contain $Recycle.bin folders. These are often quite large in size.

I can't access them without taking ownership.

What's the recommended way to clean these folders out?

Comment: this maybe relevant for you. [Clear the Recycle Bin For All Users in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://serverfault.com/questions/330776/clear-the-recycle-bin-for-all-users-in-windows-server-2008-r2)

Answer (score 2):

Check the properties of the file and these should owner/user.

Log into the user and empty the recycle bin then logout and sign back into your current user refresh Treesize and they should be gone.